# Changing nav bar 'home' link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I wanted to add a home button to my wordpress theme so that when a user goes to another page, by pressing the 'home' button they can return to the home page. However to add a page link to the nav bar I had to create a page on wordpress called home, however when you click this it goes to `www.example.com/home` rather than `www.example.com` (I understand why it does this)

Usually I would just add the `href` and '`home`' to a `nav bar` to get it to do what I need. However the way my theme gets the nav bar is through some php code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('depth' => 3)); ?>
```

This gets the `nav bar` and displays it in the source code as:

```
<div class="menu"><ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-101">
            <a href="http://www.louismoore.net/wordpress/home/">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-64">
            <a href="http://www.louismoore.net/wordpress/photos/">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-65">
            <a href="http://www.louismoore.net/wordpress/projects/">PROJECTS</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

All I need to do is remove home from the `href` for the home link and it will go to the page I want it to. However I'm not sure how to do this as it gets the `nav bar` by php.

Comment: How did you build this menu? Menu builder? Manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a Home page at all.

Do this:

1. Go to Appearance > Menus
2. Create a new menu (you have to name it something, just call it "Main Menu" or anything you want).
3. Select the pages from the left column that you want in your new menu, but do not select the Home page you made.
4. After adding those pages, create a custom menu option called "Home" and use the domain URL as the link (such as http://www.mydomain.com/")
5. Add the new link to your menu and click-n-drag it to the top position
6. CLICK SAVE MENU OR YOU'LL LOSE IT
7. Select the new menu from the options in the dropdown on the top left.

You should now have a custom menu with a home link.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the setting globally.  Login to your admin section and browse to Settings > Reading.  In "Front page displays" choose "A static page" and select your Home page as the "Front page" dropdown item (see screenshot).

You should be able to confirm that the permalink in your page (edit view) is pointing to your root domain now.

[image]